# windows-10 How to permit application execution instead of error "This app has been blocked by your system administrator"?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-10, uac

When trying to run an EXE I'm getting the error "This app has been blocked by your system administrator".  How can I configure the Software Restriction Policies to allow the user to install the software?

**CONTEXT**

- User running the EXE:

  - Non-Administrator that is only a member of `BUILTIN\Users`.
  - Name `notadm`.
- Application EXE:

  - Type of app: installer built with InstallAnywhere 2017
  - Manifested to require elevated privileges i.e. it has the User Access Control shield icon.
  - Located in `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`.
- Computer Running EXE:

  - Operating System: Windows 10 Professional.
  - Joined to test domain MAXTEST.
  - Hostname `MAX1`.
- Domain Controller to which computer is joined:

  - Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2.
  - Installed Active Directory and made it a domain controller.
  - Domain name `MAXTEST`.

I'm just double-clicking on the EXE to run it.

I'm fine with a policy that prompts.

Both the Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10 machine are running all defaults.

I've searched and found references to App Locker, Group Policy Management Console, and Remote Server Administration Tool but I'm confused about which approach to use with Server 2012 and Windows 10.  I've also read many serverfault entries that discuss using rsop.msc and gpresult.exe but none of them seem to clearly explain how to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you are not currently using AppLocker, that is not what is preventing the application from running.  If it were, an event would be logged in the AppLocker event log.